# Symfony 2.7 - Email Validation YML does not work (ignores email line all together)

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, email

I am attempting to create a symfony form which will reject if there is no email address (or an improperly formatted email address) submitted.
So here is an example of what is going on.

1. I submit with no text in the email input: it fails with the not
   blank error (good)
2. I submit 'fajncaineanf' and it fails with the 
   not blank error when it should be failing with the email error (and 
   it is obviously not blank so this makes no sense...)
3. I remove the NotBlank validation check from the YML and submit 'fajncaineanf' and it successfully submits the form. Does this not prove that the validation for - Email is broken somehow?

See code below.

Builder:

```
$builder
    ->add('emailAddress', 'email', 
        array(
            'label' => 'Email Address:',
            'data' => $user->getEmailAddress(),
            'required' => true,
            )
        )
```

YML:

```
properties:
    emailAddress:
        - NotBlack: ~
        - Email:
            message: "This email is not valid."
            checkMX: true
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: just for note, why you use YML instead of annotations?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with a constraint directly in your Builder. I like to have all in one place and not in separate files.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
```

Then you can use it in your Builder something like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('email', null, array(
        'required' => false,
        'constraints' => array(
            new Email()
        )
    ));
```

For me its much easier and i hope that can solve your problem and its a way for you to use your constraints.

Comment: We have a central location for storing validation separate from the forms (something that would involve a greater undertaking to alter) so this isn't really an option. Strangely enough, though this will produce the correct email error, typing 'sdcacacbref' also gives the not blank error... which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What is if you change the order and put the Email validation before the Email validation?

Comment: Even removing the NotBlank just allows the form to submit successfully (even when it should not)